# Add meta data to menu items

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes, 7

I have a Drupal website where many custom modules are implemented. These modules create custom rendered pages which are linked to menu items. This way a menu item represents a custom rendered page. Some other menu items are linked to node instances.

My goal is to provide meta data to each of these menu items. The meta data I want to add to each menu item are 'page description', 'user notes' and eventually term references (taxonomy).

Is there a way to add meta data to each of my menu items?

One possible solution I can come up with is creating a content type that wraps custom rendered pages with a 'description', 'user notes' and 'tags' field. Then I would create a node for each of my custom rendered pages and link the nodes to the menu items. But I'm wondering if there aren't more elegant solutions..

Answer (score 0):

Use [Menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module. The module currently allows you to set the following attributes for each menu item:

```
Id
Name
Target
Rel
Class
Style
Accesskey
```